# How to check if a key is being pressed right now

Tags: events

All:

I wonder how can I detect a key holding in the browser. For example:

I have a DIV on the page, and when I press ctrl key, then I can drag it around on the page, right now, I have implement the drag part, but how to enable that drag only when I hold ctrl key?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify any languages, so a general solution:

You can use a boolean value, and listen for the `keyup` and `keydown` events for the `body`.

In these events, toggle the value of the boolean value.  This way you can always check if the key is pressed by accessing the value of the boolean.

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try.

Comment: If this solved your problem, please mark it as the answer.

Comment: still trying, I have give the point, but need to try out see if I can highlight the nike sign.